# Setup triggers in JProfiler for the remote connection

Tags: jprofiler, heap-profiling

I have JProfiler 10 connected to the remote server via `Quick Attach`. [image]

Is there a way to enable triggers to save snapshots on timer? So far I have been unsuccessful with getting this to work on remote connection.

It works as expected on local connections.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "Quick attach" session, but create a new session of type "Attach to remote JVM" on the "New session" tab of the start center. Then, you can configure triggers for that session.

Comment: Connecting via `New Session` hasn't made a difference. Snapshot save is not being triggered on timer.

Comment: Where are you looking for the snapshot? It will be saved on the remote machine, relative to the working directory of the profiled JVM.